# <% if current_user.id == @status.user_id %> when user not signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Currently, I have in my 'show' view for a question model

```
    <% if current_user.id ==  @question.user_id %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(@question) %>
    <% else %>

    <% end %>
```

To allow the user that created the question to edit it. This works fine when a user is logged in.

However, if a guest is not logged in. I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Questions#show
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

It doesn't seem to like this line

```
 <% if current_user.id ==  @question.user_id %>
```

Can anyone advise a rewrite to get this to work with guest users too?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not do something like `<% if current_user == @question.user %>`? Take out the IDs.

Or if you really want the IDs. something like `<% if current_user.present? && current_user.id == @question.user_id %>`

Comment: Thanks! Both worked perfectly! Went with the second one! Cheers!

Comment: Or `<% if current_user.try(:id) == @question.user_id %>`

Answer (score 1):

In a helper

```
def current_user?(user)
  current_user && current_user == user
end
```

Then in the view

```
<% if current_user?(@question.user) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<% if current_user.present? && current_user.id ==  @question.user_id %>
```

Comment: while `and` looks nicer, it has a lot lower precedence and can lead to nasty bugs.

Comment: Its not about precedence here ... It would have been if I have used both.

Comment: Moreover with `and` I am doing short-circuit, means later part of the condition will not be executed if there is no current_user

Comment: Probably the person who has down voted doesn't know the difference between `&&` , `and`

Comment: i think @sevenseacat is talking about precendence of operators and not this code.  in ruby `&&` is evaluated first before `and`. more info here http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence

Comment: @Amit - && will short circuit, just as "and" does.

Comment: Thanks jvnill ... I know about that precedence. Thanks @MaxWilliams didn't knew that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `user.id` if the user is not in the database. There is a good screencast about this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0):

@BillyChan - for that requirement, i would allow upvoting if someone isn't signed in.  No need to create an unsaved user record.  I'd probably want to use cookies to stop people multiple-upvoting, but to be honest i'd probably argue with the client that we shouldn't let people upvote without being logged in.

Comment: is this meant to be a comment on the below answer?